# ROS dies when wifi disconnects temporarily

Tags: ros, wifi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS across two machines: robot and workstation

When the wifi on the robot disconnects (might happen when switching AP's), the ros processes die.

I tried using 127.0.0.1 for ROS_MASTER and ROS_HOSTNAME which solves the issue but my workstation cannot connect to the robot. I also tried using 0.0.0.0 for ROS_MASTER and ROS_HOSTNAME but ROS doesn't like it.

I've also tried ssh port forwarding but ROS uses many ports.

The command that I run on the robot is:

roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch and roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/tmp/my_map.yaml

The command that I run on the wokstation is
roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch

How to solve this issue ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215036/ros-dies-when-wifi-disconnects-temporarily/) by [robotSamir](https://answers.ros.org/users/23419/robotsamir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used openVPN to create tun0 and then used that interface for ROS.

---

Originally posted by [robotSamir](https://answers.ros.org/users/23419/robotsamir/) with karma: 46 on 2015-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you could install screen https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen on the turtlebot, ssh in to it, run the launch file and then detach the screen so that if the wifi is disrupted then the processes do not die.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-08-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotSamir](https://answers.ros.org/users/23419/robotsamir/) on 2015-08-03**:
This is not the problem. The issue isn't that the terminal is closed; the issue is that the wlan0 interface loses its ip for a little bit.
In other words, this behaviour happens even if i start the processes locally on the the robot.